# Running apt-get install within Docker container: "Unable to connect to deb.debian.org" part-way through installing dependencies

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, debian

I'm trying to build a docker container on a Raspberry Pi 3B. I need to install `gpac` for `MP4Box`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt update && apt install curl gpac -y

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "broadcast.py"]
```

I'm running this and an nginx container through docker-compose, but when trying to do `docker-compose up` I get errors while it tries to do the `apt install`. It will install the first 22 dependencies fine, but eventually it'll spit out a ton of "Unable to connect to deb.debian.org" errors. Tried this on two Raspberry Pis and it happened on both.

```
Building broadcast
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.8-buster
 ---> dcccf302a1db
Step 2/6 : RUN apt update && apt install curl gpac -y --fix-missing
 ---> Running in 582606d4320b

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.                                                                                                                  

Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [121 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main armhf Packages [201 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [7697 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main armhf Packages [7848 B]
Fetched 8145 kB in 8s (1037 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.                                                                                                                  

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
curl is already the newest version (7.64.0-4+deb10u1).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus gpac-modules-base liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libaom0 libapparmor1 libasound2
  libasound2-data libass9 libasyncns0 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58
  libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libcaca0 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1
  libcodec2-0.8.1 libdbus-1-3 libdc1394-22 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common
  libdrm-etnaviv1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfaad2 libflac8
  libflite1 libfreenect0.5 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
  libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgme0 libgpac4 libgsm1 libiec61883-0
  libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libllvm7 libmad0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0
  libmysofa0 libnorm1 libogg0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0
  libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2
  libsamplerate0 libsdl1.2debian libsdl2-2.0-0 libsensors-config libsensors5
  libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsnappy1v5 libsndfile1 libsndio7.0
  libsodium23 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2
  libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau-va-gl1 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx5 libwavpack1 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwrap0 libx11-xcb1 libx264-155
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0
  libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxv1
  libxvidcore4 libxxf86vm1 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all xkb-data
Suggested packages:
  default-dbus-session-bus | dbus-session-bus libasound2-plugins alsa-utils
  libbluray-bdj jackd2 libportaudio2 opus-tools pulseaudio libraw1394-doc
  lm-sensors serdi sndiod sordi speex
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus gpac gpac-modules-base liba52-0.7.4 libaacs0 libaom0 libapparmor1
  libasound2 libasound2-data libass9 libasyncns0 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58
  libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2
  libbs2b0 libcaca0 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1
  libcodec2-0.8.1 libdbus-1-3 libdc1394-22 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common
  libdrm-etnaviv1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfaad2 libflac8
  libflite1 libfreenect0.5 libgl1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa
  libglvnd0 libglx-mesa0 libglx0 libgme0 libgpac4 libgsm1 libiec61883-0
  libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libllvm7 libmad0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0
  libmysofa0 libnorm1 libogg0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0
  libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2
  libsamplerate0 libsdl1.2debian libsdl2-2.0-0 libsensors-config libsensors5
  libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsnappy1v5 libsndfile1 libsndio7.0
  libsodium23 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2
  libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau-va-gl1 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvpx5 libwavpack1 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwrap0 libx11-xcb1 libx264-155
  libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0
  libxcb-sync1 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6
  libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxv1
  libxvidcore4 libxxf86vm1 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all xkb-data
0 upgraded, 133 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 54.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 287 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libapparmor1 armhf 2.13.2-10 [89.6 kB]
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libapparmor1 armhf 2.13.2-10 [89.6 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdbus-1-3 armhf 1.12.16-1 [190 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf dbus armhf 1.12.16-1 [217 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libglvnd0 armhf 1.1.0-1 [49.1 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm-common all 2.4.97-1 [13.8 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm2 armhf 2.4.97-1 [35.7 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm2 armhf 2.4.97-1 [35.7 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libglapi-mesa armhf 18.3.6-2+deb10u1 [71.7 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libx11-xcb1 armhf 2:1.6.7-1 [190 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxcb-dri2-0 armhf 1.13.1-2 [100 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxcb-dri3-0 armhf 1.13.1-2 [100.0 kB]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxcb-glx0 armhf 1.13.1-2 [114 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxcb-present0 armhf 1.13.1-2 [99.0 kB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxcb-sync1 armhf 1.13.1-2 [102 kB]
Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxfixes3 armhf 1:5.0.3-1 [20.6 kB]
Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxdamage1 armhf 1:1.1.4-3+b3 [14.2 kB]
Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxshmfence1 armhf 1.3-1 [8592 B]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxxf86vm1 armhf 1:1.1.4-1+b2 [20.2 kB]
Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxxf86vm1 armhf 1:1.1.4-1+b2 [20.2 kB]
Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm-amdgpu1 armhf 2.4.97-1 [25.8 kB]
Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm-etnaviv1 armhf 2.4.97-1 [19.7 kB]
Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm-nouveau2 armhf 2.4.97-1 [24.2 kB]
Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libdrm-radeon1 armhf 2.4.97-1 [28.7 kB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Get:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8 [11.3 MB]
Err:22 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libllvm7 armhf 1:7.0.1-8
  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.78.133). - connect (113: No route to host) [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:23 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libsensors-config all 1:3.5.0-3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:24 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libsensors5 armhf 1:3.5.0-3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:25 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libgl1-mesa-dri armhf 18.3.6-2+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:26 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libglx-mesa0 armhf 18.3.6-2+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:27 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libglx0 armhf 1.1.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:28 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libgl1 armhf 1.1.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:29 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libglu1-mesa armhf 9.0.0-2.1+b3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:30 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libgpac4 armhf 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-5
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:31 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf liba52-0.7.4 armhf 0.7.4-19
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:32 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libasound2-data all 1.1.8-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libasound2 armhf 1.1.8-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:34 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libfaad2 armhf 2.8.8-3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:35 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libusb-1.0-0 armhf 2:1.0.22-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:36 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libfreenect0.5 armhf 1:0.5.3-1+b2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:37 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libopus0 armhf 1.3-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:38 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libsamplerate0 armhf 0.1.9-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:39 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libjack-jackd2-0 armhf 1.9.12~dfsg-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:40 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libmad0 armhf 0.15.1b-10
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:41 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libogg0 armhf 1.3.2-1+b1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:42 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libasyncns0 armhf 0.8-6
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:43 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libflac8 armhf 1.3.2-3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:44 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvorbis0a armhf 1.3.6-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:45 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvorbisenc2 armhf 1.3.6-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:46 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libsndfile1 armhf 1.0.28-6
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:47 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libwrap0 armhf 7.6.q-28
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:48 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxi6 armhf 2:1.7.9-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:49 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxtst6 armhf 2:1.2.3-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:50 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libpulse0 armhf 12.2-4+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:51 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libslang2 armhf 2.3.2-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:52 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libcaca0 armhf 0.99.beta19-2.1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:53 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libsdl1.2debian armhf 1.2.15+dfsg2-4
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:54 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libtheora0 armhf 1.1.1+dfsg.1-15
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:55 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxv1 armhf 2:1.0.11-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:56 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libxvidcore4 armhf 2:1.3.5-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:57 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf gpac-modules-base armhf 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-5
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:58 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libaom0 armhf 1.0.0-3
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:59 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libva2 armhf 2.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:60 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libva-drm2 armhf 2.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:61 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libva-x11-2 armhf 2.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:62 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvdpau1 armhf 1.1.1-10
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Ign:63 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavutil56 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
Err:64 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libcodec2-0.8.1 armhf 0.8.1-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:65 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libgsm1 armhf 1.0.18-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:66 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libmp3lame0 armhf 3.100-2+b1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:67 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libshine3 armhf 3.1.1-2
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:129 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvdpau-va-gl1 armhf 0.4.2-1+b1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:130 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf mesa-va-drivers armhf 18.3.6-2+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:131 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf mesa-vdpau-drivers armhf 18.3.6-2+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:132 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf va-driver-all armhf 2.4.0-1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:133 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf vdpau-driver-all armhf 1.1.1-10
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Get:63 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavutil56 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [238 kB]
Get:63 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavutil56 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [238 kB]
Get:71 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libswresample3 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [90.5 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:73 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libvpx5 armhf 1.7.0-3+deb10u1 [460 kB]
Get:78 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavcodec58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [4501 kB]
Get:78 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavcodec58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [4501 kB]
Get:78 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavcodec58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [4501 kB]
Get:78 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavcodec58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1 [4501 kB]
Err:78 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavcodec58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.64.204). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.0.204). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.192.204). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (151.101.128.204). - connect (113: No route to host) [IP: 151.101.64.204 80]
Err:89 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavformat58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:97 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libpostproc55 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:99 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libswscale5 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:104 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libzmq5 armhf 4.3.1-4+deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:105 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavfilter7 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Err:125 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main armhf libavdevice58 armhf 7:4.1.4-1~deb10u1
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]
Fetched 1644 kB in 12min 31s (2190 B/s)
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-7/libllvm7_7.0.1-8_armhf.deb  Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (199.232.78.133). - connect (113: No route to host) [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                                                                                                                                                                       
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors-config_3.5.0-3_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                      
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors5_3.5.0-3_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                          
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_18.3.6-2+deb10u1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                   
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/libglx-mesa0_18.3.6-2+deb10u1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                      
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libglx0_1.1.0-1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                             
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libglvnd/libgl1_1.1.0-1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                              
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libglu/libglu1-mesa_9.0.0-2.1+b3_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                     
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gpac/libgpac4_0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-5_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/a52dec/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-19_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                            
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-data_1.1.8-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                          
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.1.8-1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                             
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/faad2/libfaad2_2.8.8-3_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                                  
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libu/libusb-1.0/libusb-1.0-0_1.0.22-2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                     
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libf/libfreenect/libfreenect0.5_0.5.3-1+b2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/opus/libopus0_1.3-1_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                                     
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libsamplerate/libsamplerate0_0.1.9-2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                 
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jackd2/libjack-jackd2-0_1.9.12~dfsg-2_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                   
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libm/libmad/libmad0_0.15.1b-10_armhf.deb  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 199.232.78.133 80]                            
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libo/libogg/libogg0_1.3.2-1+b1_armhf.deb  
E: Aborting install.
ERROR: Service 'broadcast' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install curl gpac -y --fix-missing' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

(log trimmed to get under the StackOverflow character limit)

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being wifi issues. Switching to a wired connection fixed the issues I was having.